# Mailgun EU domain throws 401 in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun, mailgun-api

I am integrating mailgun eu domain but I don't know why the eu domain is not working in my node.js application. My mailgun domain is also verified.

When I try to create a message using the mailgun api it always throws a 401 Forbidden error.

I also checked my `MAILGUN_SECRET_KEY` and it is also correct.

Here my code

```
import 'dotenv/config'
import formData from 'form-data';
import Mailgun from 'mailgun.js';

class MailgunService {    

    constructor() {
        this.apiKey = process.env.MAILGUN_SECRET_KEY;
        this.domain = process.env.MAILGUN_DOMAIN;
        this.mailgunClient = this.setupClient();
    }

    setupClient() {
        const mailgun = new Mailgun(formData);
        return mailgun.client({
            url: 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net', // default
            username: 'api',
            key: this.apiKey,
        });
    }

    sendMail() {
        const messageData = {
            from: "replace_with_your_email",
            to: "replace_with_your_email",
            subject: "Hello",
            text: "Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!"
        };

        this.mailgunClient.messages.create(this.domain, messageData)
            .then(msg => console.log(msg)) // logs response data
            .catch(err => console.log(err)); // logs any error
    }
}

export default MailgunService;
```

Error:

[image]

I expect I can send emails using an EU domain.

Comment: First guess would be maybe you didn’t whitelist your IP address.

Comment: Yes I do not whitelist my IP address. Now it is fixed. Thanks @JasonOlson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely because you need to explicitly **whitelist** your server's IP address with Mailgun via the [IP Allowlist](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012244474-IP-Allowlist).

- To the following page: https://app.mailgun.com/app/account/security/api_keys
- Click the API security tab
- In the IP whitelist section, click the Add to whitelist button.
- Finally, enter the IP / CIDR and click the Save IP address/CIDR button.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to update the allow list for this scenario. There were two issues:

1. Get the correct API Key (from Sending > Domain Settings > Sending API Keys)
2. Set the url for the client as shown above:

   ```
   mailgun.client({
     url: 'https://api.eu.mailgun.net', // default
     username: 'api',
     key: API_KEY_FROM_STEP_ONE,
   });
   ```